# Golang gin proxy to handle svelte frontend and Golang api

Tags: go, proxy, svelte, go-gin

I am trying to write a proxy for my api and frontend using Golang and gin. If the request goes to anything except "/api" I want to proxy to svelte server. If goes the "/api/something" I want to handle it in gin. Currently my code is like this.

```golang
func proxy(c *gin.Context) {
    remote, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:3000")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(remote)
    proxy.Director = func(req *http.Request) {
        req.Header = c.Request.Header
        req.Host = remote.Host
        req.URL.Scheme = remote.Scheme
        req.URL.Host = remote.Host
        req.URL.Path = c.Param("proxyPath")
    }

    proxy.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.Any("/*proxyPath", proxy)

    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

Now if I go to `http://localhost:8080` I am seeing my svelte app. But if a want to add any other route I get an error saying `panic: catch-all conflicts with existing handle for the path segment root in path '/*proxyPath'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mv proxy func in r.NoRoute
`r.NoRoute(proxy)`

Comment: I would use that but I also need to access proxyPath variable. Without that everything will go to the same address.

Comment: You can access the path with c.Request.Path.Url in your proxy function